# How to use basic commands in webdriver.io

Tags: webdriver-io

I'm using webdriver.io to do some browser automation.  Not really testing , just saving time by automating things. I can see examples of how to use some of the functions .. but I can't seem to access them. I'm quite new to node.js

** Important ** I realise you can use browser.getAttribute - but looking at this example: http://webdriver.io/api/property/getAttribute.html

I should be able to execute getAttribute on the element object..?

```
var allInputs = $$('.loginForm input')
console.log(allInputs.map(function(el) { return el.getAttribute('name'); }))
```

My code:

```
var webdriverio = require('webdriverio');
var options = {
    desiredCapabilities: {
        browserName: 'chrome'
    }
};

var browser = webdriverio.remote(options)

async function browserTest(){

await browser
    .init()
    .url('http://www.google.com')
    .getTitle().then(function(title) {
    console.log('Title was: ' + title);
    })
.catch(function(err) {
    console.log(err);
});

var body = await browser.element("//body")

console.log(body)

//the following line fails
console.log(await body.getAttribute("id"))
```

}

browserTest()

Comment: what exactly are you having trouble with? You gave some good snippets of the code but no errors? What is going wrong that you need help with?

Comment: If you see the code .. I comment on which line fails . Something about no “getAttribute...”

Comment: `browser.element("//body")` doesn't look right to me. It should be `browser.element("body")`. Maybe that's your problem?

Comment: I think current there are some issues using async/await on browser.element (https://github.com/webdriverio/webdriverio/pull/2404). Try `await browser.getAttribute('body', 'id')`